# Some themes make my font multiple sizes. How can I disable this?

Tags: fonts, themes, colors

I like the colors from these beautiful themes, but I wish I could disable the font resizing.[image: Here's an example.]

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to be heavy-handed about it, you could wipe out the `:height` attribute of every defined font except for `default`

```el
(defvar face-height-whitelist nil
  "List of faces for which the :height attribute should be
  preserved by the function `remove-face-heights'")

;; source: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/23949/93
(defun remove-face-heights ()
  "Unset the :height attribute for every face except for
`default' and any faces listed in `face-height-whitelist'"
  (mapc
   (lambda (face)
     (unless (or (eq face 'default)
                 (memq face face-height-whitelist))
       (set-face-attribute face nil :height 'unspecified)))
   (face-list)))

(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'remove-face-heights)
```

Adding the above code to your init file would wipe out the `:height` attribute on any faces that are defined after emacs is initialized.  If along the way you find out that there are some face heights that you want to preserve, you can add those faces to `face-height-whitelist` like this:

```el
(add-to-list 'face-height-whitelist 'some-special-face)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this is to set the `:height` attribute for the faces that you want to use. for example I have something like this in my config.

```
(defvar jat/default-font-size 100)
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height jat/default-font-size)
(set-face-attribute 'org-document-title nil :height jat/default-font-size)
```

Comment: Note that you can use `customize-face` to edit a face and save it so that the edits are automatically restored on next launch; this saves you from having to edit your init file manually. Use `M-x customize-face RET org-document-title RET`, for instance